# Attempted debugging Azure Windows App Service from Visual Studio 2022 claims to be Linux App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a Debug connection to a Asp.Net Core (.Net6) website on Azure but I get a message telling me that Remote Debugging is not available for Linux Azure App Services. By all indications, the App Service is a Windows app service.

Any thoughts why this is happening and what I can do to "fix" it?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried destroying the app service and recreating it? Maybe you didn't make a mistake, maybe Azure did.

Comment: In my case, I restarted the VS, rebuilt by solution, published, and tried to attach the debugger again. It worked.

Comment: Same problem here. Usually happens when failing to attach debugger to the remote. Next try gives me this error. It fails kind of randomly though, and don't specify exactly why, only that it couldn't connect after filling in the credentials and connecting for a while. Seems like restarting VS is enough for me, though, but I seem to have to refresh aad credentials on my VS user every time to be able to connect to the service again.